# Display components if there is an authenticated user

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

In an angular 7 app, I am learning to implement authentication following the angularfire2 document [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md). I set up my app.component.html file like this

```
<app-login *ngIf="!authService.user"></app-login>

<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="(authService.user | async) as user">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- navigation sidebar -->
    <div class="col-2 pt-5" id="sideNav">
      <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    </div>

    <!-- main content area -->
    <main class="col-10 offset-2">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

So if there is an authenticated user, the login component will not be rendered. I have a authenticate.service.ts that uses `AngularFireAuth`

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { auth } from "firebase/app";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthenticateService {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    console.log("logged in");
  }
}
```

My login.component.ts imports the authenticate service and tries to signin the user when they provide the email and password

```
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthenticateService } from "../services/authenticate.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user = null;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  tryLogin(loginForm: NgForm) {
    const email = loginForm.value.email;
    const password = loginForm.value.password;

    console.log(email, password);

    this.authService.signinUser(email, password);
  }
}
```

My login component renders as expected and i see the console.log message expected when i try to login but my view doesn't change as expected - which is to render div containing the navigation and main content area.

How do I achieve my goal and am I missing something the way I am doing it right now?

Comment: What is `authService.user` is AppComponent?

Comment: `authService.user` is suppose to call an instance of  `AngularFireAuth.user` like its used here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `signInWithEmailAndPassword` should be async, so you need to wait for it to resolve:

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(response => console.log(response));
```

I'm not sure what the exact type of response will be, but you should probably save it in your auth service:

```
export class AuthenticateService {
  public user: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null); // Add type accordingly

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(response => { console.log('Logged in!'; this.user.next(response); });
  }
}
```

Add your `authService` to AppComponent:

`constructor(private myAuthService: AuthenticateService ) {}`

And look for the logged in user in `app.component.html` like this:

```
<app-login *ngIf="!(myAuthService.user | async)"></app-login>

<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="(myAuthService.user | async) as user">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- navigation sidebar -->
    <div class="col-2 pt-5" id="sideNav">
      <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    </div>

    <!-- main content area -->
    <main class="col-10 offset-2">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, this is what I was trying to achieve. One thing though using `async` threw an error so I called it without async and it worked. What I did was to set the public user declared in `AuthenticateService` so there was no need to use async. Now i can import the service anywhere in my app and use the user there.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to your authState

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
   // your code
});
```

There you can set your user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :-

In signin.component.ts

```
 onSignIn(form: NgForm){
            const email = form.value.email;
            const password = form.value.password;
            this.authService.signInUser(email, password);
        }
```

In AuthService.ts

```
signInUser(email: string, password: string) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(
                response => {
                   //check if response is correct here
                    this.router.navigate(['your_component_route']);
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
                        .then(
                            (token: string) => this.token = token
                        )
                }
            ).catch(
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
```

So basically you have to redirect it where you want to redirect using router.navigate[(['Your_Route'])]

Comment: This would redirect me to the same login page. What I want is to render the main content div with navigation only when there is a user after signin is successful. If there is no user, the login component is rendered that is why I have to check for a user when the root page is visited.

Comment: I have used / for my dashboard you can make a redirect to whatever component you want using router.navigate[(['Your-component-route'])]